# Defining Pyomo multidimensional parameters using slices

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm using Pyomo to model a certain optimization problem, in the past I've only used parameters from at most two dimensions, however now I'm trying to define a 4 dimensional parameter using slices. The most convenient way for me is to define slices that are 2x2 matrices, here is an example of what I want with valid syntax in AMPL:

```
param d:=

[*,*,1,1]:  1   2   3   4   5   6 :=
1   0.00    3.47    3.31    3.27    3.26    0.00
2   3.47    0.00    0.18    4.97    6.03    3.47
3   3.31    0.18    0.00    4.81    5.86    3.31
4   3.27    4.97    4.81    0.00    1.81    3.27
5   3.26    6.03    5.86    1.81    0.00    3.26
6   0.00    3.47    3.31    3.27    3.26    0.00

[*,*,2,1]:  1   2   3   4   5   6 :=
1   0.00    3.47    3.31    3.27    3.26    0.00
2   3.47    0.00    0.18    4.97    6.03    3.47
3   3.31    0.18    0.00    4.81    5.86    3.31
4   3.27    4.97    4.81    0.00    1.81    3.27
5   3.26    6.03    5.86    1.81    0.00    3.26
6   0.00    3.47    3.31    3.27    3.26    0.00;
```

However, I think this syntax is not valid in Pyomo. The Pyomo documentation shows how to define parameters through slices using templates of tuples, for example:

```
set A := (a,1,a,1) (a,2,a,2) (b,1,b,1) (b,2,b,2);
param B :=
[*,1,*,1] a a 10 b b 20
[*,2,*,2] a a 30 b b 40
;
```

But would prefer to use a matrix format similar to AMPL. Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?